# Windows Phone - pointermove doesn't work - event is fired, but event is empty

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, dom-events, swipe

I'm working on application which is using swipe function. And is working perfectly on Android and iOS, but it doesn't work on Windows Phone.
There are some similar issue, but related to case when `pointermove` is not fired. But in my case `pointermove` is fired, but event object is empty.
Initially I was testing this on Cordova App, but then I tried other methods, and generally:

1. when I've create sample JS App for Windows Phone 8.1 it works. It means that event listener receive event with params like X,Y position of a pointer,
2. when I've create sample Windows Phone Application (XAML), and I've tried to do the same within WebView it doesn't work.
   XAML has grid with

```html
<WebView x:Name="WebView1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

This WebView then load an simple HTML with JS code described below.

3. It doesn't work on sample Cordova Apps as well

```js
function touchStartHandler(e) {
  console.log("Touch Pointer Move: " + JSON.stringify(e));
}

document.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", touchStartHandler, false);
```

For 1) case event is fine, for 2 and 3 I just got:

> Touch Pointer Move: {}

And nothing else.

I've tried `pointermove` event as well.
And the application has style `touch-action:none;` set.

Tested on Lumia 830 and 930 (Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2).

It looks to be some issue with WebView on Windows Phone, but maybe somebody has a clue how it can be solved.

Comment: Which platform target are you using in cordova? `wp8` or `windows`?

Comment: windows phone, but the issue is not related to cordova. My first idea was that this is cordova issue. But then I've created regular Windows Phone App from Visual Studio, I've added just WebView control to it, and had some issue... so Cordova is just sending what it gets. Target in VS was set to Windows Phone 8.1